# Post запрос выполняется вечно используя HttpClient PostJsonAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient, asp, blazor

Есть клиент (blazor) и WebApi (asp.net core mvc). Для связи использую HttpClient. Все Get запросы работают, а вот с Post нет. Если послать Post запрос он приходит на сервер и обрабатывается правильно, но после отправки результата клиент зависает навсегда.
Сервер:

```
[Route("api/Token")]
[ApiController]
public class TokenController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUserEntity> userManager;

    public TokenController(
        IJwtTokenService tokenService, 
        UserManager<ApplicationUserEntity> userManager, 
        IMapper mapper
        )
    {
        _tokenService = tokenService;
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    [Route("api/Token/Registration")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Registration([FromBody] TokenViewModel tokenViewModel)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        var applicationUser = new ApplicationUserEntity()
        {
            UserName = tokenViewModel.Email,
            Email = tokenViewModel.Email
        };
        var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(applicationUser, tokenViewModel.Password);
        if(!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return StatusCode(500);
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

Клиент:

```
@page "/Registration"
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Services.IUriHelper UriHelper
@inject HttpClient Http


<h1>Registration</h1>
<form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
    <fieldset>

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" bind="@Email"/>
        <span class="pure-form-message">This is a required field.</span>

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" bind="@Password"/>

        <label for="remember" class="pure-checkbox">
            <input id="remember" type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>

        <button type="submit" onclick="@SubmitForm" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Register</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>

@functions{
    public string Email { get; set; } = "";
    public string Password { get; set; } = "";

    private async Task SubmitForm()
    {
        WebBlazor.Models.ViewModels.TokenViewModel tokenViewModel = new Models.ViewModels.TokenViewModel
        {
            Email = Email,
            Password = Password
        };
        var response = Http.PostJsonAsync<object>("https://localhost:44328/api/Token/Registration", tokenViewModel).Result;
        Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
        UriHelper.NavigateTo("/Login");
    }
}
```

На клиент полностью зависает при отправке запроса.

При запуске в режиме отладки и нажатии на кнопку я вижу что запрос приходит и результат отдается: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Но клиент зависает.

Пост запрос на api проверен:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пардон, а в какую консоль пишет blazor? Браузерный `console.log` понимаю, а куда блейзор пишет? И можете ли вы просто поставить брейкпойнт на строку с cw - то он до неё доходит? А то "зависание" может быть разным: не отработал переход на другой url, завис на выводе в какую-то консоль...

Comment: @A K, blazor воспринимает консоль как console.log. Брейкпоинт к сожалению в blazor пока не поддерживает.  После PostJsonAsync можно писать что угодно из-за ожидания потока, клиент все равно зависает намертво.

Comment: сделай валидный запрос через "почтальона" https://www.getpostman.com/ - скажи что получил

Comment: @dgzargo, сервер проверял неоднократно с ним все в порядке. Приложил картинку с проверкой расширением arc вместо getpostman.

Comment: @лалалалала к сожалению, я почти полностью не понимаю создание страниц на html+css+js. на последок: ты написал "`inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Services.IUriHelper UriHelper`". почему там `интерфейс`? это нормально? ниже (в самом низу) ты обращаешься к нему как к экземпляру класа или у него есть статические методы?

Comment: @dgzargo, я использую blazor. Это фреймворк который позволяет использовать .net среду вместо javascript. Для написания страничек html с кодом C# microsoft придумала файлы cshtml в них для создания объекта с использованием DI есть ключевое слово "inject".  Так что это строка просто создает объект UriHelper класс который определен в настройках сервера.

Comment: @лалалалала последняя идея: сравнить запрос который кидает клиент с валидным запросом. ты дебажил уже - значит оно зависает на последних двух строчках того ассинхронного метода. ага, а выщовов `await` я не вижу. ты посылаешь запрос синхронно

Comment: @dgzargo, в конце запроса я добавил ".Result" так как с асинхронным методом сайт продолжит работать не дожидаясь результата. В то время как второй поток, неизвестно что, будет делать вечно, не отдавая результат.

Comment: "зависает" - страница не отвечает? в ASP.net только три варианта: 400, 500, 200. там не указано что страница должна куда-то переходить или что-то показывать

Comment: @dgzargo, страница не отвечает.

Comment: Вы в запросе ожидаете объектный результат, а в ответе выводите Ok(), что соответствует пустому ответу. Попробуйте возвращать OkObjectResult() с сущностью, которую необходимо получить.

Answer (score 0):

Не используйте блокируещие вызовы для асинхронных методов в Blazor это будет приводить к блокировке

```
private async Task SubmitForm()
{
    WebBlazor.Models.ViewModels.TokenViewModel tokenViewModel = new Models.ViewModels.TokenViewModel
    {
        Email = Email,
        Password = Password
    };
    var response = await Http.PostJsonAsync<object>("https://localhost:44328/api/Token/Registration", tokenViewModel);
    Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
    UriHelper.NavigateTo("/Login");
}
```